# Specify summary group labels dynamically in gt package

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

I want to dynamically create summary group labels for rows created by row_group_summary in the gt package. A simplified example follows.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

# create example dataframe for gt
df <- data.frame(A = c('grp1' , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 B = c('grp1' , 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                 C = c('grp2' ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15) ,
                 D = c('grp2' ,24, 30, 1, 7 , 16))
row.names(df) <- c('Group', 'One' , 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five')
df_new <- data.frame(t(df)) %>%
  mutate(across(One:Five , ~as.numeric(.)))

# gt table without summary figures
gt(df_new)

# create totals for groups
df_new %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%
  gt() %>%
  row_group_order(c('grp1' , 'grp2')) %>%
  summary_rows(
    groups = c('grp1' , 'grp2') , 
    columns = c(One:Five) ,
    fns = list(
      list(label = 'Total' , fn = 'sum')))
```

Running the example shows a table with the summary row label "Total" for both totals in the 2 groups. However, I would like the summary row labels to be "Total, grp1" and "Total, grp2", dynamically using the row group labels to generate the modified summary row labels. I have tried different approaches using sprintf to generate summary row labels in this way, without success.

Is there a way to do this--ideally within gt and tidyverse packages? Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a more easier out-of-the-box option which I have missed. But one option to achieve your desired result would be to use `purrr::reduce` to add the total rows one by one like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df_new %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  gt() %>%
  row_group_order(c("grp1", "grp2")) %>%
  purrr::reduce(c("grp1", "grp2"),
    ~ summary_rows(
      .x,
      groups = .y,
      columns = c(One:Five),
      fns = list(
        list(label = paste0("Total, ", .y), fn = "sum")
      )
    ),
    .init = .
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Stefan, that resolved the problem perfectly. I am not very familiar with purrr and obviously need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- data.frame(A = c('grp1' , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 B = c('grp1' , 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                 C = c('grp2' ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15) ,
                 D = c('grp2' ,24, 30, 1, 7 , 16))
row.names(df) <- c('Group', 'One' , 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five')
df_new <- data.frame(t(df)) %>%
   mutate(across(One:Five , ~as.numeric(.)))

df_new |> 
   group_by(Group) |> 
   gt() |> 
   (function(x) {
      
      df = x
      
      y = df$`_stub_df`$group_id |> unique()
      
      for (c in y) {
         
         df <- df |> 
            summary_rows(
               columns = everything(), 
               groups = c, 
               fns = list(list(label = paste0("Total: ", c), fn = "sum"))
               )
         
      }
      
      return(df)
      
   })()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).